# CardView.setRadius() is not working when assigned programmatically

Tags: java, android

So in my program, I want to generate CardViews dynamically on a predefined Layout that I intend to place inside a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation, which is inside a horizontal ScrollView. Everything in the code works fine except:

```
cv.setRadius(Tools.convertDpToPx(context,5));
```

[cv is a CardView Object]

[Tools.convertDpToPx(context,float) resides in Tools as static function and returns translated values in Pixels from DP]

Tried getting **cv.getRadius()** to check if my values are getting assigned, and they are.

Does anyone have an idea why the **setRadius()** is not working?

**IMPLEMENTATION OF CODE**

```
CardView cv = new CardView(context);
// Set external card view wrapper(cv) properties
CardView.LayoutParams cvlp=new CardView.LayoutParams(Tools.convertDpToPx(context,155),Tools.convertDpToPx(context,200));
cvlp.leftMargin=Tools.convertDpToPx(context,10);
cv.setLayoutParams(cvlp);
cv.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#002038")));
cv.setPreventCornerOverlap(false);
cv.setRadius(Tools.convertDpToPx(context,5));
//And more elements added to Card View Layout
cv.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

Comment: Could you show more of your code, we need to know where you call `setRadius()`.

Comment: @JakobF Question updated as requested

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding a Background or Background Color to a CardView will remove Rounded Corners.

Comment: Use `setCardBackgroundColor()` instead of `setBackground()`. The "card" _is_ the background; don't override it.

Comment: Or, if you don't want a simple color, use a `FrameLayout` inside of your `CardView` and then set the background of the FrameLayout.

Comment: so is there any solution to this? I want to define Backgroundcolor as well as radius programatically.

Answer (score 0):

My solution: add a LinearLayout(or other) inside the Cardview ,change backgroundColor of LinearLayout instead using `setBackgroundColor`

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/video_card_duration_size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
          ...
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

in java code

```
linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(SurfaceColors.SURFACE_2.getColor(context));
```